# SOAP PHP and angular

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, soap

I'm trying to consume a SOAP Web Service used in a PHP file.

When I access the PHP file directly, it works. (http://bacly.fr/baclymphp/getffbadsample.php)

When I try to access it from an AngularJS  like this:

```
function loadwsffbad() {
   var players={}
   var urlphp="http://localhost/cordova/mbacly/www/php/";

   $http.get(urlphp+"getffbadsample.php").then(function(data) {
      players = data.data;
      console.log(players);
   },function(status) {
      alert("pas d accès réseau");
   });
}
```

I get this in console:

```
Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in C:\wamp\www\cordova\mbacly\www\php\getffbadsample.php on line 5
```

I saw in other posts that I need to check that SOAP is enabled on the server, which is the case (http://bacly.fr/baclymphp/info.php), As it works directly with the php file, I guess it is not the pb.

getffbadsample.php:

```
<?php
$clientSOAP = new SoapClient('http://ws.ffbad.com/FFBAD-WS.wsdl');

$Auth["Login"]="******";
$Auth["Password"]="*****";
//Encodage de vos identifiants en Json (sérialisation des objets)
$AuthJson = json_encode($Auth);
$Query["Function"]="ws_getresultbylicence";

$Query["Param"]["Licence"]="06468814";

$QueryJson = json_encode($Query);
//Appel de la fonction distante
$Return = $clientSOAP->getResult($QueryJson,$AuthJson);
echo $Return;
?>
```

Thank for your help.

Comment: need to json_encode() your data . javascript can't read  php `stdClass Object`

Comment: @charlietfl l removed the json_decode, so now i get some json data from my direct call. (see edit).
I get the same error from javascript call